# how to create a flex container with dynamic height and scrollbar

Tags: css, list, flexbox, scrollbar

here are the conditions for the styles. My main objective is to achieve this effect with CSS only. But last resort is to involve JS if there is no other way.

1. when 1st ul tag has very few items and 2nd ul tag has many items, 2nd ul can grow to take up all the remaining spaces.
2. Then, when 1st ul starts to grow, 2nd ul has to shrink so 1st ul can grow.
3. Until 1st ul and 2nd ul have same height, both do not grow and shrink anymore but fixed at the equal height for both ul.
4. Step 1-3 apply too when 1st ul has many tags and 2nd ul has few tags. Long ul should always "borrow" space from short tag.
5. Both ul have scrollbar when they have more items than given space.

Below is the codes I have been working on. It almost works like what I expected but with one issue. The ul tag does not stop at certain height when both ul have equal height. One ul would just continue to grow to make the other ul shrinks.

Codepen link : https://codepen.io/Lee-Yuan-Hooi/pen/WNYJKQj

You can try it by adding more li tags to the 2nd ul. It grows insted of keeping at a certain height.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>Online CSS Editor</title>

  <head>
    <style>
      .parent {
        background: grey;
        max-height: 90vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        /* Set the overflow to hidden for the parent element */
      }

      .test {
        overflow: hidden;
        /* Set the overflow to hidden for the .test elements */
      }

      .ul-container {
        flex-grow: 1;
        /* Allow the ul containers to grow and take up the available space */
        overflow-y: auto;
        /* Add a vertical scrollbar if needed */
      }

      ul {
        margin: 0;
        background: yellow;
        opacity: 0.5;
        overflow-y: auto;
        /* Add a vertical scrollbar if needed */
      }

      p {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <p style="background: green;">2323232323</p>
      <div class="test ul-container">
        <p>Title 1</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>

          <!-- Add fixed number of items here -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p style="background: purple;">2323232323</p>
      <p style="background: blue;">2323232323</p>
      <div class="test ul-container">
        <p>Title 2</p>
        <ul>
          <!-- Add fixed number of items here -->
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 1</li>

          <!-- Add more items here -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <p style="background: red;">2323232323</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

----------------------------EDIT---------------------------------

Let's say now 1st ul has way more items than 2nd ul. In this case, 1st is very long and 2nd ul is short. When I add more items to 2nd ul, 2nd starts to grow while 1st ul shrinks.

If I continue to add more items to 2nd ul, eventually 2nd ul will continue to grow until it becomes too long and 1st ul continues to shrink to become very short.

What I desire at this point is when I add more items to 2nd ul(when 2nd ul is shorter than 1ul), 2nd grows until it reaches a point where it has the same height with 1st ul. Once both ul have same height, both stop growing/shrinking and fix the height

Comment: Are you saying that the second list will always be longer than the first and that you want the height of the second list to shrink to fit the first list without the first list having a scrollbar until both lists are displayed at the same height?

Comment: @TimR Opps. Let me reclarify it. "Long" ul should always "borrow" space from "short" tag.

Comment: I don't understand how the current result differs from what you are asking for.

Comment: Let's say now 1st ul has way more items than 2nd ul. In this case, 1st is very long and 2nd ul is short. When I add more items to 2nd ul, 2nd starts to grow while 1st ul shrinks. 

If I continue to add more items to 2nd ul, eventually 2nd ul will continue to grow until it becomes too long and 1st ul continues to shrink to become very short. 

What I desire at this point is when I add more items to 2nd ul(when 2nd ul is shorter than 1ul), 2nd grows until it reaches a point where it has the same height with 1st ul. Once both ul have same height, both stop growing/shrinking and fix the height

Comment: I posted an answer earlier just to show demonstrations but deleted it because I thought maybe I figured out what you were asking for. However, I still don't understand, so I undeleted my "answer" (not actually an answer, just a demonstration.)

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it and don't understand how the current result differs from what you are asking for. I commented out CSS declarations that are unnecessary.

I changed the unordered lists to ordered lists in these runnable snippets just to easily see the number of list items.

With 20 items in both lists

```css
.parent {
  background: grey;
  max-height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  /* Set the overflow to hidden for the parent element */
}

.test {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  /* Set the overflow to hidden for the .test elements */
}

.ul-container {
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
  /* Allow the ul containers to grow and take up the available space */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Add a vertical scrollbar if needed */
}

ol {
  margin: 0;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
  /* Add a vertical scrollbar if needed */
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p style="background: green;">2323232323</p>
  <div class="test ul-container">
    <p>Title 1</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>

      <!-- Add fixed number of items here -->
    </ol>
  </div>
  <p style="background: purple;">2323232323</p>
  <p style="background: blue;">2323232323</p>
  <div class="test ul-container">
    <p>Title 2</p>
    <ol>
      <!-- Add fixed number of items here -->
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>

      <!-- Add more items here -->
    </ol>
  </div>
  <p style="background: red;">2323232323</p>
</div>
```

7 items in the first list, 20 in the second list

```css
.parent {
  background: grey;
  max-height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  /* Set the overflow to hidden for the parent element */
}

.test {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  /* Set the overflow to hidden for the .test elements */
}

.ul-container {
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
  /* Allow the ul containers to grow and take up the available space */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Add a vertical scrollbar if needed */
}

ol {
  margin: 0;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
  /* Add a vertical scrollbar if needed */
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p style="background: green;">2323232323</p>
  <div class="test ul-container">
    <p>Title 1</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>

      <!-- Add fixed number of items here -->
    </ol>
  </div>
  <p style="background: purple;">2323232323</p>
  <p style="background: blue;">2323232323</p>
  <div class="test ul-container">
    <p>Title 2</p>
    <ol>
      <!-- Add fixed number of items here -->
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>

      <!-- Add more items here -->
    </ol>
  </div>
  <p style="background: red;">2323232323</p>
</div>
```

20 items in the first list, 10 in the second list

```css
.parent {
  background: grey;
  max-height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  /* Set the overflow to hidden for the parent element */
}

.test {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  /* Set the overflow to hidden for the .test elements */
}

.ul-container {
  /* flex-grow: 1; */
  /* Allow the ul containers to grow and take up the available space */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Add a vertical scrollbar if needed */
}

ol {
  margin: 0;
  background: yellow;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
  /* Add a vertical scrollbar if needed */
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p style="background: green;">2323232323</p>
  <div class="test ul-container">
    <p>Title 1</p>
    <ol>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>

      <!-- Add fixed number of items here -->
    </ol>
  </div>
  <p style="background: purple;">2323232323</p>
  <p style="background: blue;">2323232323</p>
  <div class="test ul-container">
    <p>Title 2</p>
    <ol>
      <!-- Add fixed number of items here -->
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>

      <!-- Add more items here -->
    </ol>
  </div>
  <p style="background: red;">2323232323</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's best to view the snippets in "full page" and toggle device emulation if necessary to get an appropriate-sized viewport that is tall enough to show a significant portion but short enough to have scrollbars.

Comment: Fpr "With 20 items in both lists", when more items are added to 1st ul, 1st ul should stay at the height equal to 2nd ul while new items are added within the scrollbar. However, 1st ul grows to consume more space(causing 2nd ul to shrink).Same to when more items added to 2nd ul

For "7 items in the first list, 20 in the second list", when 13 more items added to 1st list, 1st list grows to the same size as 2nd list(desired behavior). But when 14th item added to 1st list, first list grows to be longer than 2nd list(instead of keep the same height)